# An Exception of Type Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement was encountered while inserting the data

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to insert values into my database with a write function, but it doesn't seem to want to work despite the compiler showing me it has gotten all four values I'm trying to pass it. Here's what I've got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'baseballDataSet.Baseball' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.baseballTableAdapter.Fill(this.baseballDataSet.Baseball);
            this.myDataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //write
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Baseball.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
            myConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            OleDbTransaction myTrans;

            // Start a local transaction
            myTrans = myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Chaos);
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            myCommand.Transaction = myTrans;

            try
            {
                myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Baseball (PlayerName,Team,JerseyNumber,BattingAverage) VALUES (" + this.textBox1.Text + "," + this.textBox2.Text + ", '" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "');";
                label6.Text = myCommand.CommandText;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myTrans.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("All records are written to database.");
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                try
                {
                    myTrans.Rollback();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    if (myTrans.Connection != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An exception of type " + ex.GetType() +
                            " was encountered while attempting to roll back the transaction.");
                    }
                }

                label5.Text = "An exception of type " + ee.Message +
                    " was encountered while inserting the data.";
                label5.Text += "No record was written to database.";
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable;
            dataTable = new DataTable("myDataGrid");
            DataColumn dtCol = null;//Data Column variable
            DataColumn dtCol2 = null;//Data Column variable
            DataColumn dtCol3 = null;//Data Column variable
            DataColumn dtCol4 = null;//Data Column variable
            DataColumn dtCol5 = null;//Data Column variable

            dtCol = new DataColumn("ID");
            dtCol2 = new DataColumn("PlayerName");
            dtCol3 = new DataColumn("Team");
            dtCol4 = new DataColumn("JerseyNumber");
            dtCol5 = new DataColumn("BattingAverage");

            dtCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            dtCol.DefaultValue = 0;
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol);

            dtCol2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol2.DefaultValue = "";
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol2);

            dtCol3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dtCol3.DefaultValue = "";
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol3);

            dtCol4.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"); ;
            dtCol4.DefaultValue = 0;
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol4);

            dtCol5.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double"); ;
            dtCol5.DefaultValue = 0;
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtCol5);

            DataRow newRow1;

            string mySelectQuery = "SELECT Id, PlayerName, Team, JerseyNumber, BattingAverage FROM Baseball";
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Baseball.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
            myConnection.Open();

            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

            OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    newRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
                    newRow1[0] = myReader.GetInt32(0);
                    newRow1[1] = myReader.GetString(1);
                    newRow1[2] = myReader.GetString(2);
                    newRow1[3] = myReader.GetInt32(3);
                    newRow1[4] = myReader.GetDouble(4);

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow1);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                myReader.Close();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            this.myDataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go to run it by pressing the appropriate button, the labels I've placed to show me what's going on show me at least three different exception errors, ranging from "no value given for one or more required parameters" to "error in INSERT INTO statement" to "Syntax error (missing operator)". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's getting all the values, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Firstly go read up on SQL Injection attacks and see why your code is dangerous. Secondly, your query is missing quotes around your string inputs.

Comment: I understand about wanting to prevent SQL injection, but this is for a school assignment, so I'm not too concerned about that as I am about getting it working. I get it though, good practices and all.

Comment: Either way, the second point is still valid.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the query missing the quotes? I've tried putting quotes around the appropriate inputs, but it doesn't like that.

Comment: For example `VALUES (" + this.textBox1.Text + ",` should be `VALUES ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO Baseball (PlayerName,Team,JerseyNumber,BattingAverage) 
   VALUES (" + this.textBox1.Text + "," + this.textBox2.Text + ", '" + 
     this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "');";
```

should be

```
"INSERT INTO Baseball (PlayerName,Team,JerseyNumber,BattingAverage) 
   VALUES ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" +
     this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "');";
```

Note the single quotes in this.textBox1.Text and this.textBox2.Text

Comment: Oh geez, that makes so much sense now! Thanks!